# sheet email merge with script and html coding multiple people and different links

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mailmerge

I have added many (80+) to a google form to prepopulate the form and have them go in and initial in and fix any missing data on the form. I am sending everyone an email reminder of the program and would like to send their link to the form at the same time using script in google sheets.
I put this script together after finding something similar online in youtube, but struggling with the html coding in my email to send out to each person.

```
function sendEmail() {
var email = 0;
var name = 1;
var link = 2;

var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Email")

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var wsSettings = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings");

var name = wsSettings.getRange("B2").getValue();
var subject = wsSettings.getRange("B1").getValue();

var data = ws.getRange("A2:D" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

data = data.filter(function(r){ return r[3] == true });


data.forEach(function(row){
  emailTemp.e = row[email];
  emailTemp.n = row[name];
  emailTemp.l = row[link];
  var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    row[email],
     subject, 
     "Your email doesn't support HTML.",
     {name: "name", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
     );

});

}
```

```html
Here is my html for my email message:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>  
<p><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-family: 'arial black', sans-serif;">Dear <?= n ?>,</span><br /><br />This email will take you to the pre-populated Google Form used to record attendance for <span style="font-family: 'arial black', sans-serif;"><strong>Supporting Children and Families in our Community</strong></span> on January 22, 2021, held from 12:00-3:00 pm.<br /><br />Please visit this <strong><span style="color: #0000ff;">Link</span></strong> to complete any missing data and initial in before clicking on the submit button. <span style="color: #ba372a;">You will only be able to sign-in for the training on January 22, 2021</span>, so do not forget to complete the form if you would like a certificate for attending or SCECHs. </span></p>
<p><span style="font-family: arial;">If you know <strong><span style="color: #843fa1;">someone that is attending that did not receive an email with a form to complete</span></strong>, please have them contact me ASAP so they have a form to complete to sign-in.</span></p>
<p><span style="font-family: arial;">To reach the zoom presentation for <strong>Supporting Children and Families in our Community,</strong> please click here. The link will only work on January 22, 2021, near the start time.</span></p>
<p><span style="font-family: arial;"><br />If you have any questions or concerns, please let me know.</span></p>
<p><span style="font-family: arial;"><br />Best Regards,<br /><span style="font-family: 'arial black';">Erika Rupert</span><br />Bay-Arenac ISD<br /><strong><a href="mailto:ruperte@baisd.net">ruperte@baisd.net</a></strong><br /><br />&nbsp;</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am struggling because the link is different for each person.
Here is the form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1gb6rmbx9EjWSfyRAJyVt3HojIcsMApGZhZRDThDm40g/edit?usp=sharing which is populated for each person who registered to attend.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Note, I cannot add a Google app unless my organization has approved it. Most are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

To include a link in HTML you need an a tag.

You would need to include the below in your html code where the Link is to create a clickable item that brings up the webpage the user needs:

```js
<a href="<?= l ?>">Link</a>
```

I didn't get on that well with your code for sending emails, one that does work is below:

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rng = sh.getDataRange();
  var val = rng.getDisplayValues();
  var lr = rng.getLastRow();
  var name = sh.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var subject = sh.getRange("B1").getValue(); 
  for (var i = 1; i < lr; i++) {
    if (val[i][0] != ""){
      var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Email');
      html.e = val[i][0];
      html.n = val[i][1];
      html.l = val[i][2];
      var htmlMessage = html.evaluate().getContent();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(
        val[i][0],
      subject, 
      "Your email doesn't support HTML.",
      {name: name, htmlBody: htmlMessage}
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I cannot get this to work as there is an error. Attempted to execute sendEmail, but could not save. This is the error I am getting: Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var' line: 12 file: Code.gs (Line 12 reads: html.e = var[i][0]; from your code above.

Comment: Change ```html.e = var[i][0]``` to ```html.e = val[i][0]``` and it will work

Comment: Here is my new code based on your comments. I am still struggling to get the send email to work.

Comment: How do I add my code for you to see my issue? I am getting an HTML error on line 17 which is GmailApp.sendEmail(   - Before this error I was receiving an error that my HTML was wrong

Comment: I did receive the email after all, but still no links so I must have those wrong. Do I put the links in the HTML code or do those pull from my script page? This is how one of my links HTML reads: <p>To reach the zoom presentation for <strong>Supporting Children and Families in our Community, </strong><a href="=1?&gt;">this link</a> will only work on January 22, 2021, near the start time.<br />